# Matroid isomorphisms and self-duality

Tags: combinatorics, definition, matroids

The *uniform matroid* $U(n,k)$ has $n$ elements and all $k$-element subsets are bases. I was under the impression that $U(2k,k)$ is *self-dual*, that is, it is *isomorphic* to its dual in which bases are replaced by their complement.

However, the usual definition of matroid isomorphism seems to be the following:

> **Definition.** Two matroid $(X_1,I_1)$ and $(X_2,I_2)$ are *isomorpic*, if there exists a bijection $X_1\to X_2$ that induces a bijection $I_1\to I_2$.

It is not hard to see, that this defintion cannot provide an isomorphism between, e.g. $U(4,2)$ and its dual. No permutation of the elements of the matroid can induce the following map on the characteristic vectors of the bases:

$$0011\longleftrightarrow 1100,\qquad 1010\longleftrightarrow 0101,\qquad 1001\longleftrightarrow 0110.$$

What now? Is $U(4,2)$ not self-dual? Or is there a different version of matroid isomorphism, e.g. the following:

> **Definition.** Two matroids $(X_1,I_1)$ and $(X_2,I_2)$ are isomorphic if their lattices of independent sets are isomorphic as lattices.

And if so, which one is the "standard definition"?

Comment: Your second definition does not handle loops or parallel elements correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are hoping that the map that does the dualizing already is the isomorphism if a matroid is self dual. That doesn't need to be the case. $U(2k,k)$ and its dual are isomorphic through the identity map but that is a different map than the one that maps each element in $U(2k,k)$ to its dual.